# Get token decrypted data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am struggling with how to get my user decrypted data for the current user, basicly everytime a user does login he get a token at the moment.

After i login i can capture a phote and send it to the server, following my code you guys can see that this request needs a token to work.

Basicly i have a problem related to my app.js(starting file) i try to set a app.use that needs a token for all the routes that comes after the register and login, like this:

```
app.use('/',require('./routes/index'));

app.use(jwtPermission);
router.use('/fotos',fotos);
```

my jwt permission file:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var jwtConfig = require('../config/jwt');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("entered");

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
          console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']);
    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token,jwtConfig.secret, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });
    }
}
```

router index(connection to authentication and fotos files)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
 console.log('Time: ', Date());
 console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
 console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
 next(); //passa a solicitação para a próxima função de middleware na pilha
});

router.use('/',require('./authentication'))
router.use('/fotos',require('./fotos'));

router.use(function(req,res,next){
    return res.status(404).json({Error:"Invalid Url"});
})

module.exports = router;
```

when i point to /fotos it doesn't enter the jwtPermission as i want, what is wrong?

Comment: can you please provide part of code where you're connecting router to your app

Comment: updated, my authentication works well, and i can post a foto eveything fine, just the token authorization it doesn't need 1 to execute so basicly the jwtPermission is not even working

Answer (score 0):

you can add your token validation middleware before function that handles some route. For example:

```
router.use('/fotos', jwtAuthentication, require('./fotos'));
```

Comment: not working, he still let me add the foto even without a token, doesn't enter the jwtAuthentication